# Fail to restart yarn node-manager in ambari

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, ambari, bigdata

I am new bee for ambari and yarn, and I don't have any other configuration for my new flash ambari machine.

the ambari version is latest, and here is the yarn.py address:
ambari-server/src/main/resources/common-services/YARN/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/yarn.py

I have found out some potencial solutions like thie,https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/11907/nodemanager-fails-to-start-io-error-lock.html and https://reviews.apache.org/r/38098/diff/1/, however, it doesn't work.

I have offer the all right to the log directory.

```
2016-05-24 11:36:17,712 FATAL nodemanager.NodeManager (NodeManager.java:initAndStartNodeManager(528)) - Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB$DBException: IO error: /data/var/log/hadoop-yarn/nodemanager/recovery-state/yarn-nm-state/LOCK: Permission denied
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartRecoveryStore(NodeManager.java:177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:525)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:573)
Caused by: org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB$DBException: IO error: /data/var/log/hadoop-yarn/nodemanager/recovery-state/yarn-nm-state/LOCK: Permission denied
        at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB.checkStatus(NativeDB.java:200)
        at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB.open(NativeDB.java:218)
        at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory.open(JniDBFactory.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.recovery.NMLeveldbStateStoreService.initStorage(NMLeveldbStateStoreService.java:930)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.recovery.NMStateStoreService.serviceInit(NMStateStoreService.java:204)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        ... 5 more
2016-05-24 11:36:17,738 INFO  nodemanager.NodeManager (LogAdapter.java:info(45)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at hadoop134.linesum/192.168.21.134
```

Comment: Check /data permissions. When you try to change permissions, don't forget to use "-R". Ex: `chmod -R 655 /data`

Answer (score 2):

First of all try to check the permission :

```
ls -l /data/var/lib/ | grep hadoop
```

In your case, you will find something like this :

```
d---------. 4    root         root          44 Apr 5 09:45 hadoop-yarn
```

You must do two things :

**Change user and group to yarn :**

```
chown -R yarn:yarn data/var/log/hadoop-yarn
```

**Change permission to 755 :**

```
chmod -R 755 data/var/log/hadoop-yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permission of */data/var/log/hadoop-yarn/nodemanager/recovery-state/yarn-nm-state/* this file to 700 or even 777

Command: *chmod 777 /data/var/log/hadoop-yarn/nodemanager/recovery-state/yarn-nm-state/*

Answer (score 0):

You need to check who is the user trying to access the file. Most probably it is the "yarn" user. Run the following command on your Ambari machine

```
    sudo chown -R yarn:yarn /data/var/log/hadoop-yarn
```

If it works, you are good else try to check the nodemanager output and log files for more information.